# Getting Scenes Thumbnails using Amazon Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-processing, amazon-rekognition

I have a task to generate thumbnails of each scene change in video using AWS Cloud.

Basically, I am interested in an alternative to Azure Video Indexer, which returns all the information about video including all the thumbnail for each scene changes.

AWS Rekognition can provide information about the scenes but I need to have images for scenes.

I am only interested in Out-of-the-box solutions as an alternative to Azure VI, cause we are not deciding between two clouds.

I can see that AWS MediaConvert has ability to generate thumbnails from video using Web Interface, but I can't find a good sample on how to do that using SDK.

Can you please give a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Rekognition does work with videos such as detecting inappropriate or offensive content in a video, detecting people in video, and so on. Its about detecting content in videos.

However  Amazon Rekognition does not generate thumbnails from videos in the manner you want. To perform this use case, you need to use https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/.

Here is a good blog that can get you started:

[Create a poster frame and thumbnail images for videos using AWS Elemental MediaConvert    .](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/create-a-poster-frame-and-thumbnail-images-for-videos-using-aws-elemental-mediaconvert/)

This blog will teach you how to perform this via the Console. Then you can apply that to an SDK such as Java v2 using the [Interface MediaConvertClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/mediaconvert/MediaConvertClient.html).

Comment: Thanks. Mostly solve my task